# Custom Element Listener For animationend

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Can a listener for `animationend`  be done like this?

The below listener `animationend` is  not firing from my custom keyframe `.fire-ripple {animation: ripple 0.65s linear;}`;
`@keyframes ripple {
  /*scale the element to 250% to safely cover the entire link and fade it out*/
  100% {opacity: 1; transform: scale(2.5);}
}`

---

```
      listeners: { 'animationend': 'removeRipple' },
      removeRipple: function() {
        rippleElement = document.getElementById('ripple-element');
        rippleElement.classList.remove('fire-ripple');
      },
```

---

I could do `el.addEventListener('animationend'...` but I am trying to keep it Polymer convention like.

Note: I know about paper-ripple, I'm using my own ripple on purpose

Comment: I guess my first question is, did you check to see if the animationend event was actually firing? In other words, does the el.addEventListener approach work?

Comment: Side note, you probably want to be using the Polymer dom API wrappers. I.E. `Polymer.dom(rippleElement).classList.remove('fire-ripple');` Polymer's shady-dom (a lightweight polyfil of shadow-dom) requires using the Polymer APIs in order to work correctly. See here: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#dom-api